# Need a regular expression for (from time to to time ) text box in asp.net

Tags: expression

Need a regular expression for text box in asp.net ( i am using vb.net as code behind)

hh:mm am/pm  - hh:mm am/pm

2:30 pm - 3:45 pm

I want to put mask edit for this., so that users know the format.

hh:mm am/pm  - hh:mm am/pm

Comment: Great - did you try anything on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends exactly what you are trying to achieve, what the constraints are and the language you are using but this may help:

```
/[0-9][0-9]?:[0-9][0-9] [ap]m - [0-9][0-9]?:[0-9][0-9] [ap]m/g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
am|pm
```

will match `am` or `pm`.

```
0?\d|1[0-2]
```

will match an hour.

```
[0-5]\d|60
```

will match a minute.

Put them together:

```
^(0?\d|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d|60) (am|pm) - (0?\d|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d|60) (am|pm)$
```